# Ionic v3 with wordpress api works with android but not with ios

Tags: wordpress, ionic-framework, ionic3, wordpress-rest-api

i working on ionic app using v3 i used wordpress as backend some of api working well but some of it gives errors like:

> WARN: Unhandled rejection TypeError: Request header field User-Agent is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

it happens on ios only when i build for android or web it works well.

for example i can register a new user but i can't login with any user.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line to the .htacess :

> Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Headers
> "Content-Type,Access-Control-Allow-Headers"